# Not able to click button with Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, frame

I'm trying to click a button using Selenium, but everytime I get the message that it can't find the element. This happens even when I put a time.sleep() in front of it.

```
time.sleep(5)

                #Click on download
                downloadButton = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#downloadButton')
                time.sleep(5)
                downloadButton.click()

                #Click on close
                closeButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btnZorgAnnuleren"]')
                closeButton.click()
```

The button is inside of a frame (not iframe), but I don't know how to switch to it. Here is the frame source code and page source code: https://www.codepile.net/pile/ZoG0REzQ. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I do not see any iframe or frame tag though. nor `downloadButton` neither `btnZorgAnnuleren`

Comment: I have added a new link. Does this work for you @cruisepandey? When I right click on the pop-up, I get the option to view frame source. This means that there's a frame right? I assumed so.

Comment: I can see the content now, but do not see ` downloadButton  `or` btnZorgAnnuleren `, can you try the same and search using CTRL  + F to see if it works at your end

Comment: FCan you do this.. open chrome -> go to dev tools (by pressing F12) then  - > elements -> then do a CTRL + F and type //frame or //iframe.. you would see matches in the console

Comment: You're right! When I inspect element, it does show up, but when I view page source, it doesn't. I just saw the iframe ID in the inspect element code. My bad, I'm gonna try it with that. I'll keep you posted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If it's iframe :

the I would suggest you to switch to frame like this (with explicit waits):

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "iframe ID")))
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

once you have switched you can click like this :

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#downloadButton"))).click()
```

and click on close  :

```
 wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "btnZorgAnnuleren"))).click()
```

and once you are done, you should switch to default content like this :

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```