# How to handle dynamic iFrame ID in Python (Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium

I have an iFrame I want to switch to, but the iFrame generates a random ID everytime. How can I switch to this iFrame. The resource stays consistent as far as I can tell.

UPDATE:for click on download it works, but for click on close it doesn't.

```
<iframe id="e674" src="/resource.ashx/636625958320000000/du/webviewer/html5/Reader.html?setLng=en#d=%2Fdocumentviewer.ashx%2FDownloadDocument%3FstateId%3Dv3x4o%26cacheInfoKey%3D1arhoq9%2F1arhoq9-1o5aabb.json&amp;auto_load=false&amp;languageUrl=%2Fresource.ashx%2F636625958320000000%2Fdu%2Flocalization.json%3Fdisplay%3D__lng__&amp;custom=%7B%22permissions%22%3A65535%2C%22showToolbar%22%3Atrue%2C%22showSidePane%22%3Atrue%2C%22singlePageRotation%22%3Afalse%2C%22downloadUrl%22%3A%22%2Fdocumentviewer.ashx%2FDownloadSource%3FstateId%3Dv3x4o%26cacheInfoKey%3D1arhoq9%2F1arhoq9-1o5aabb.json%22%2C%22downloadAsPdfUrl%22%3A%22%2Fdocumentviewer.ashx%2FDownloadAsPdf%3FstateId%3Dv3x4o%26cacheInfoKey%3D1arhoq9%2F1arhoq9-1o5aabb.json%22%7D&amp;filepicker=0&amp;preloadWorker=1&amp;pdfnet=0&amp;pageHistory=1&amp;subzero=1" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true"></iframe>


driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@name='rwDocumentviewer']"))

                time.sleep(3)

                driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[contains(@src,'webviewer/html5/Reader.html')]"))

                #Click on download
                downloadButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="downloadButton"]')
                downloadButton.click()

                time.sleep(3)

                #Click on close
                closeButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btnZorgAnnuleren"]')
                closeButton.click()            

                driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68176797/not-able-to-click-button-with-selenium-python

Comment: This is a different question, as I'm discussing how to handle a dynamic iFrame (ID) here.

Comment: I have left my comment on that post as well. If that is not resolved, tell us what went wrong and why this question is required. If it looks genuine myself will definitely have a look on this question as welll

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little new to SO. I thought you were meant to start a new post when you have a new question. My apologies!

Comment: I understand that, but you can comment right whtr it worked or not when someone answer your question, I think that is also same like this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@name='rwDocumentviewer']"))

driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[contains(@src,'webviewer/html5/Reader.html')]"))
```

Comment: I get this: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//iframe[contains(@src,'du/webviewer/html5/Reader.html')]"} when I do that.

Comment: Edited my code. try that and see if it works

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the same message. Really appreciate your help though!

Comment: Is it inside another iframe? Can you check?

Comment: There are 3 when I ctrl+f: `<iframe name="rwDocumentviewer" src="DocumentViewer.aspx?nr=7147" frameborder="0" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0px;"></iframe>`, and, `<iframe style="display: none;"></iframe>`. The second one is the one in the post.

Comment: So the one you are trying to access is not inside any of the other frames you found?

Comment: It seems like the code in the post is inside of the first iframe in the comment. Is there any way I can copy the inspect element code to show you?